# PasswordSignInAsync() doesn't return any result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My code returns null for result and false for result.success.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Redirect("~/AdminArea/UserManager/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "The user name or pasword is wrong.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Also  require confirmed email set to false in my Startup.cs like blow:

```
 services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail=false);
```

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Identity.
Please help me to find problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PasswordSignInAsync() doesn't return any result` You can try to debug and check if any  `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager'` and `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager'` related logs are written to Visual Studio **Output** window.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can check first:

- Is you user correctly exist in the table AspNetUsers?
- And which values has you user in the table AspNetUsers (field EmailConfirmed must be true)?
- And the most important thing : when you use options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail=false, use the options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount=false as well!

After that, can you implement the following code :

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occured");
                return Page();
            }
```

Regards.